# general socket question

Tags: http, sockets, download, client

I'm building a client that "talks" to the http server. Now my client needs to download files simultaneously. Right now my client just opens a socket (actually Async Socket) for every connection, but I was wondering whether I could do that with just one socket?

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple requests on the same socket but they must be sequentially handled.  In [HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) this is called a persistent connection and you can accomplish it using the keep-alive header.

If you want to download 2 files individually at the same time you'd need 2 separate connections.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the keep-alive thing? Isn't it the default in http 1.1?

Comment: @Alex1987: If I remember correctly the keep-alive is defaulted to keep alive but can also be set to Close.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [RFC 2616](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc2616/) section 8 "Connections".